# Detect when another Android application exits

Tags: android

In my app, I'm launching via an Intent, a separate application over which I don't have much control. I want to detect when *that* application exits or otherwise is no longer actively executing. Is there any way to be notified when another process exits?

As far as I can tell, the best I can do is:

1. Start an unbound Service which will poll for the given Package ID to be started
2. Start the Intent
3. The service polls `ActivityManager` at a fixed interval, to determine when the separate application exits
4. The service does the work it needs to do, then exits itself.

Is there any less poll'y way to do this?

Comment: Well, if when the application you launch finishes, it calls `finish()`, you could simply use `startActivityForResult()`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: What is your definition of "exits" or "is no longer activity executing"? After all, that process may hang around for days, depending upon the nature of the other app. "Is there any less poll'y way to do this?" -- probably not, and your technique probably will stop working with the next Android release, as `ActivityManager` is being locked down more.

Comment: @hichris123 I'm already using `startActivityForResult`, but I'm launching the app's MainLauncher, it's not expecting to return a result or explicitly call `finish`

Comment: @CommonsWare Good question, and I totally realize that this entire approach is not ideal / hacktastic. The app I'm polling is a game, and I'm generally waiting until the app is killed via the task screen, or via being pushed out of memory by some unrelated app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any less poll'y way to do this?

There is no broadcast or similar event that is sent out when some other process is terminated. Hence, whatever you do will involve polling.

Also, as I hinted at in my comment, `getRecentTasks()` and `getRunningTasks()` on `ActivityManager` are deprecated as of the L Developer Preview and will return a reduced result set on L and higher devices. I don't know if that's what you are polling on or not.

Also bear in mind that it's entirely possible that your own process will terminate before the game's. For example, the user could be in a long game session, and Android decides to terminate your process to free up memory for other processes. The odds of this are low, given that you are using a service, but not zero.

Comment: "Also bear in mind that it's entirely possible that your own process will terminate before the game's" - Good to know, though I should be able to handle that scenario as well

Comment: Thanks for the tips @CommonsWare, especially around the L Preview stuff.